# Why Payhere payment notification not receiving

Tags: payment-gateway, moodle

I have tried to use sandbox payment using moodle and payment is successful and shown in payhere dashboard. but in moodle, the student is not enrolling and again show a payment option.

[image: error image]

but from payhere side, the call for notify is not receiving to proceed with enrollment but after send details with postman it work perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be happened because of Cloudflare. If you are using Cloudflare, check the firewall logs.

Comment: thank you this work for me, you save a lot of time for debugging.